# Detecting Session expiry on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-state

I have built a shopping cart that uses Session State to keep the shopping cart data while the user is browsing the store.

I have an issue where if I leave the browser window open for a long time on step1 of the shopping cart, then press "go to step 2", my actions throw an error because the step2 action assumes the session hasn't expired and the ShopCart object is in the correct state.

I would like this scenario to be nicer for my users, but I think i need to somehow detect if the session has expired so that on next request I can throw them to Step1.

I found the following code that claims to to solve the problem, but it doesn't work for me.

The IsNewSession condition is true but the condition

```
if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0)) {
   // handle expired session
}
```

always returns false and it never handles the invalid session. I'm confused.

Is this possible in ASP.NET (and MVC)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Way 1

Put this code in the `Init` / `Load` event of Page 2...

```
        if (Context.Session != null)
        {
            if (Context.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                string sCookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != sCookieHeader) && (sCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {

                    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    }
                    Response.Redirect("Error Page");
                }
            }
        }
```

### Way 2

Alternative you can check whether the `Session` object exists before proceeding to work with it in Page 2, like this:

```
if (Session["Key"] != null)
{
   Object O1 = (Object) Session["Key"]; 
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: What if the user is logged in and closes the browser (while session is still alive)... then returns after the session is expired?

Answer (score 15):

The King 's answer does not work for me. I have added `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` in `OnActionExcuting()`. The `Response.Redirect` will not work!

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

This is my complete method

```
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

            // check if session is supported
            if (ctx.Session != null)
            {

                // check if a new session id was generated
                if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
                {

                    // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                    // have timed out
                    string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                    if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                    {
                        string redirectOnSuccess = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
                        string redirectUrl = string.Format("?ReturnUrl={0}", redirectOnSuccess);
                        string loginUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + redirectUrl;
                        if (ctx.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                        }
                        RedirectResult rr = new RedirectResult(loginUrl);
                        filterContext.Result = rr;
                        //ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Home/Logon");

                    }
                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Ignore my knowledge but where should I declared this class (controller???), how can I use this attributes???

Comment: Sanjay, Declare it anywhere. The class is creating an attribute. You associate the attribute with your controller class(es) or Action Method(s) by applying the [SessionExpireFilterAttribute]

Answer (score 0):

### You need to create the **Session_OnEnd** method In **Global.asax.cs** file in your project.

this is my code and I am able to **Detecting Session expiry on ASP.NET MVC**

```
protected void Session_OnEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userid = 0;
    userid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
    if (userid != 0)
    {
        var userActivity = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserRepo>();
        var responce = userActivity.LogOutUsers(userid);
        if (responce == true)
        {
            Session.Clear();
            Session.Abandon();
        }
    }
}
```

[more](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1040314/How-to-call-Interface-service-from-Global-asax-cs)